# Calculating with creation and annihilation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

I'm currently taking a quantum mechanics lecture and am having trouble with the mathematical formalism.

I have to calculate the following:

$$\langle n+2|b^\dagger b^\dagger |n\rangle$$
and
$$\langle n+1| \left(b^\dagger bb^\dagger + \frac {\hat{1}}{2}\right) |n \rangle$$

for the first one I can use the notation  $ b^\dagger|n \rangle = \sqrt{n+1} |n+1 \rangle$ right? So I would get
$$\langle n+2|b^\dagger b^\dagger |n\rangle = \langle n+2|n+1|n\rangle $$
if I'm correct. Would I be done there? And how do I solve the second one?

Many thanks in advance!

Edit: Thanks for the help everyone. The answer to the first one would be: $$\langle n+2|b^\dagger b^\dagger|n \rangle = \langle n+2|b^\dagger \sqrt{n+1} | n+1 \rangle$$
$$ =\sqrt{n+1} \langle n+2|b^\dagger|n+1 \rangle = \sqrt{n+1} \langle n+2|\sqrt{n+2}|n+2 \rangle $$
$$ =\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)} \langle n+2|n+2 \rangle = \sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)} $$

And for the second:

$$\langle n+1| \left( b^\dagger bb^\dagger + \frac {\hat{1}}{2} \right) |n \rangle = \langle n+1|b^\dagger bb^\dagger |n \rangle + \langle n+1| \frac 12 |n \rangle $$
$$ = \langle n+1|b^\dagger b \sqrt{n+1} |n+1 \rangle + \frac 12 \langle n+1|n \rangle $$
$$ = \sqrt{n+1} \cdot \langle n+1|b^\dagger \sqrt{n+1} |n \rangle + \frac 12 \langle n+1|n \rangle $$
$$ = (n+1) \cdot \langle n+1|\sqrt{n+1} |n+1 \rangle + \frac 12 \langle n+1|n \rangle $$
$$ = (n+1) \sqrt{n+1}  + \frac 12 \langle n+1|n \rangle $$
$$ = (n+1)^\frac 32 $$

Can I simplify the last expression? Provided it's correct.

Edit: Made a mistake in the original question.

Edit2: In an answer below the second term can be simplified via the Kronecker-Delta notation, see Andreas Mastronikolis answer.

Comment: thank you I just edited it! Oh is it maybe $<n+2|b^\dagger \sqrt{n+1}|n+1>$

Comment: That’s the first step. You’re not done.

Comment: Hint: the states $\{|n\rangle\}$ are an orthonormal basis, $\langle n | m \rangle = \delta_{nm}$.

Comment: Hint: Numbers (non-operators) can come out of the bra and ket.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think I got the gist of it. I attempted the second one and posted in the original post

Comment: Made a few edits on your post. This looks like a classic ladder operator problem (and my best guess is that you are being taught operator methods for the harmonic oscillator). Just wanted to say (perhaps for future readers) that the relation
$$b |n \rangle = \sqrt{n} | n - 1 \rangle$$
is used although it wasn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Just continually act the operator on a bra or ket. The first one goes as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\langle n+2 |b^\dagger b^\dagger |n\rangle &= \sqrt{n+1}\,\langle n+2|b^\dagger|n+1\rangle \\
&=\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}\, \langle n+2|n+2\rangle \\
&= \sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{align}$$
because, in this case, $\delta_{mn}=\langle m | n\rangle$. Can you attempt the next one?

Comment: thank you so much for the step by step. I calculated the first one and it became much clearer to me. I just tried the second one and will post my attempt in my original post

Comment: I added my attempt at the next one, if you have the time please point out any mistakes

Comment: @Nad you've done well! The $\frac{1}{2}\langle n+1 | n\rangle$ term can be simplified; because $\langle m | n \rangle=\delta_{mn}$ for this particular basis, what does $\langle n+1 | n\rangle$ evaluate to?

Answer (score 0):

The second one looks right. As for your last question, there *is* something that can make it look simpler. Note that:
$$\langle m| n \rangle=\delta_{mn} \ \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N} \xrightarrow{m \ = \ n+1} \langle n+1|n\rangle = \delta_{(n+1)n} = 0 \text{ since } n + 1 \neq n \ \forall \, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
And thus, the final answer reduces to:
$$(n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Comment: thank you very much. can I ask you what that notation is called? Is it simply an attribute of the delta function?

Comment: @Nad Your welcome. The function that I am using, $\delta_{mn}$ is the Kronecker delta (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). It is defined as:
$$\delta_{mn} = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $m = n$} \\
0, & \text{if $m \neq n$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @Nad As for what you said about the Dirac delta. In a way, you can think of the Kronecker Delta as the discrete analog of the Dirac delta distribution. The dirac delta $\delta (x)$ takes $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and outputs $+\infty$ at $x=0$ and vanishes everywhere else. Likewise, the Kronecker delta takes in two parameters, $m$ and $n$, and outputs $1$ when they are equal, and vanishes for all other cases.